# Kafka 0.9 Spring Integration DSL Configuration

Tags: spring-integration

I've played with the latest Spring Integration DSL and got stuck on the consumer configuration.

This is my consumer config:

```
@Configuration
public static class ConsumerConfiguration {

    @Autowired
    private KafkaConfig kafkaConfig;

    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());

    @Bean
    public ConsumerFactory<String, String> consumerFactory() {
        Map<String, Object> props = new HashMap<>();
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, kafkaConfig.getBrokerAddress());
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.GROUP_ID_CONFIG, "myGroup");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.KEY_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.VALUE_DESERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringDeserializer.class);
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.AUTO_OFFSET_RESET_CONFIG, "earliest");
        props.put(ConsumerConfig.ENABLE_AUTO_COMMIT_CONFIG, true);
        return new DefaultKafkaConsumerFactory<>(props);
    }

    @Bean
    IntegrationFlow consumer() {
        log.info("starting consumer..");

        KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapterListenerContainerSpec<String, String> kafkaMDCAListenerContainerSpec =
                Kafka09.messageDriverChannelAdapter(consumerFactory(), kafkaConfig.getTopic());

        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(kafkaMDCAListenerContainerSpec)
                .<Map<String, List<String>>>handle((payload, headers) -> {
                    payload.entrySet().forEach(e -> log.info(e.getKey() + '=' + e.getValue()));
                    return null;
                })
                .get();
    }
}
```

During application startup I am getting the following exception:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'consumer' defined in class path resource [demo/DemoApplication$ConsumerConfiguration.class]: Bean instantiation via factory method failed; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow]: Factory method 'consumer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.<init>(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;)V
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:599) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1128) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1023) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:510) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:306) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:302) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:197) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:751) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:861) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:541) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:761) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:371) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:315) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1186) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1175) [spring-boot-1.4.1.RELEASE.jar:1.4.1.RELEASE]
at demo.DemoApplication.main(DemoApplication.java:162) [classes/:na]

Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate [org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow]: Factory method 'consumer' threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.<init>(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;)V
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:189) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
... 17 common frames omitted

Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.springframework.kafka.listener.adapter.MessagingMessageListenerAdapter.<init>(Ljava/lang/reflect/Method;)V
at org.springframework.integration.dsl.kafka.Kafka09MessageDrivenChannelAdapter$IntegrationMessageListener.<init>(Kafka09MessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:152) ~[spring-integration-java-dsl-1.2.0.M2.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.dsl.kafka.Kafka09MessageDrivenChannelAdapter.<init>(Kafka09MessageDrivenChannelAdapter.java:50) ~[spring-integration-java-dsl-1.2.0.M2.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.dsl.kafka.Kafka09MessageDrivenChannelAdapterSpec.<init>(Kafka09MessageDrivenChannelAdapterSpec.java:54) ~[spring-integration-java-dsl-1.2.0.M2.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.dsl.kafka.Kafka09MessageDrivenChannelAdapterSpec$KafkaMessageDrivenChannelAdapterListenerContainerSpec.<init>(Kafka09MessageDrivenChannelAdapterSpec.java:71) ~[spring-integration-java-dsl-1.2.0.M2.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.dsl.kafka.Kafka09.messageDriverChannelAdapter(Kafka09.java:148) ~[spring-integration-java-dsl-1.2.0.M2.jar:na]
at org.springframework.integration.dsl.kafka.Kafka09.messageDriverChannelAdapter(Kafka09.java:123) ~[spring-integration-java-dsl-1.2.0.M2.jar:na]
at demo.DemoApplication$ConsumerConfiguration.consumer(DemoApplication.java:149) ~[classes/:na]
at demo.DemoApplication$ConsumerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$845f73e4.CGLIB$consumer$0(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at demo.DemoApplication$ConsumerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$845f73e4$$FastClassBySpringCGLIB$$64cb05f3.invoke(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at org.springframework.cglib.proxy.MethodProxy.invokeSuper(MethodProxy.java:228) ~[spring-core-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassEnhancer$BeanMethodInterceptor.intercept(ConfigurationClassEnhancer.java:356) ~[spring-context-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
at demo.DemoApplication$ConsumerConfiguration$$EnhancerBySpringCGLIB$$845f73e4.consumer(<generated>) ~[classes/:na]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
at   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.SimpleInstantiationStrategy.instantiate(SimpleInstantiationStrategy.java:162) ~[spring-beans-4.3.3.RELEASE.jar:4.3.3.RELEASE]
... 18 common frames omitted
```

Any help is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

**SOLUTION:**
The updated and working code can be found here:
https://github.com/magiccrafter/spring-kafka09

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See, you have as a dependency:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        <scope>compile</scope>
 </dependency>
```

But that one is already for the `Apache Kafka-0.10`. The Spring Integration Java DSL isn't compatible with that yet.

We are planning to move there after Java DSL 1.2 RELEASE.

So, you have to switch to `spring-kafka-1.0.x`, or just use `spring-integration-kafka-2.1.0.RELEASE` directly, bypassing `Kafka09` factory!

Comment: Wasn't thinking about that when adding the dependencies. Thanks.